# Ifelse in R Studio

Tags: r, if-statement

Write an ifelse() statement that takes the height column and returns the height if it is greater than 72 inches and returns 0 otherwise.

> library(dslabs)
>
> data(heights)
>
> dput(df1$height)

What is the mean of the resulting vector?

Comment: This looks like a homework question.

Comment: What have you even tried?  This is typically one of the first kinds of things you are taught when you actually try to learn the language.

Comment: Can you update with `dput(df1$height)` from the original data before the transformation

Answer (score 0):

Mean of resulting vector can be obtained with mean(df$column_after_transformaion)